# Splitting large file in Stata into smaller files

Tags: stata

I have a 100 MB file in Stata containing 260 observations per company. I have about 4000 companies in my sample. So the time series data is stacked one below the other for each company, one company after the other in a single file. I want to split this file into smaller files, one file for one company. I tried using a `forval` loop in Stata and all I get is the counter 'i' is an invalid name. The loop I use is as follows:

```
   forval i=1/4000 {
   use "file.dta" if internalid=='i',clear
   save "newfile_'i'"
   }
```

Comment: It seems like your using the wrong opening quotes with your local. See the example in my answer (today I can't get the correct quotes to showup in comments).

Comment: Sounds a bad idea to me. Now you have to loop other 4000 files. Naturally there may be some special reason you are not stating.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is in long form and for many types of analysis, this is usually the best way to have it. However, if you really need to split it, here is an example:

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

input ///
id x
1 38
1 57
1 43
2 35
2 98
end

tempfile main
save `main'

*----- what you want ----

forval i = 1/2 {
    use `main' if id == `i', clear 
    save id`i'
}
```

This is a Stata [FAQ](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/save-parts-of-dataset/).

Comment: Hi Roberto, thank you for the detailed forval loop. However, I used the same Stata FAQ you have given the link to. And I get 'i' invalid name as the error. It could be the quotes for the local you mentioned. Actually instead of "file.dta" what I am using instead is "C:\Users\Windows User\Desktop\Data\timeseries_2000.dta" which specifies the location of file to be accessed for splitting. What do you suggest using then? Thanks so much for your help- Veronica

Comment: Veronica, I don't know exactly what kind of suggestion you want. If you insist on splitting the file into 4,000 other files, the code is there to do so. My only suggestion would be to use `/` instead of ``\`` as directory separators (see [Beware the backstabbing backslash](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0042) by Nick Cox). As already stated, the other suggestion is to not split the file, but the convenience of this depends on what you plan to do. The file is not too big anyways.